# Json storing or separated table

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

assume having a table of people information and want to add their children as well. so you have two options:

1- you can put child's info in JSON array and store it as a JSON string in people table

2-  you can create children table and link it to people table.

which one is better to modify and is faster?
note: the order of children is important
if there's a better way please let me know

Comment: Children are people. So just add them to the people table. In the people table add the fields father and mother. So for every 'people', when it is a child of someone else in your database, you will indicate father and or mother. You will not indicate if someone has children.

Comment: The sqlite documention on [recursive CTEs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) includes an example of such a hierarchical table, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Surely option 2.

Going with the first option will make you parse/process the JSON everytime you need to retrieve some value or want to add some data.

While Option 2 will not only make the transactions easy but will also add maintainability and scalability.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I do not totally agree with you. For having dealt with an API that stores references of objects instead of copies of the object itself, I can tell you that it a great pain to deal with such input as I had to code some process to populate my parent POJOs with child POJOs which is really both hideous and painful....